# Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value async method

Tags: javascript, firebase, ecmascript-6, promise, google-cloud-functions

I have an async method named generateSession. And I want the promises system to wait till the call is done. I wait till the data is there and than delete the row at the database. For now, that doesn't make any sense.

But I get an error at this state. `Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value` It looks like this comes from calling the generateSession. But I don't know how to fix it.

```
 exports.pending = functions.database
        .ref('/groups/{groupId}/status/pending/{deviceId}/')

    .onCreate(event => {
         generateSession().then(function(data) {
            console.log("generated session:" + data.sessionId);
            return event.data.ref.set({})
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("error:", err);
        });
    });

var generateSession = function(){
    // *** Return a promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        opentok.createSession({mediaMode:"relayed"}, function(err, session){
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(session);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onCreate` of Firebase Functions itself needs to return a Promise:

```
exports.pending = functions.database
        .ref('/groups/{groupId}/status/pending/{deviceId}/')

    .onCreate(event => {
        // You should return the result of generateSession() here
        return generateSession().then(function(data) {
            console.log("generated session:" + data.sessionId);
            return event.data.ref.set({})
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("error:", err);
            // You probably don't want to catch here, let the error
            // go through so that Cloud Functions can pick it up
        })
    });
```

Comment: Ehm. Did you change any code? Or what do I need to change? :)

Comment: Sorry! Implicit return isn't very easy to see. Edited & added an explicit return with a comment

Comment: Yes I see it, thanks! One more question, you say that you probably don't want to catch. What I want is, when an error occurs to write to the realtime database with some information. Is it possible to do that in the catch? Can I do the same like return event.data.ref.set({})?

Comment: Yes, that's fine to do that in a catch, but if that call succeeds, Firebase Functions will report the function *succeeded*, not failed. Again, that might be what you want :)

Comment: Is there a way to let Firebase Functions report an error when there is one. And do a database write?

Comment: Sure, just `return Promise.reject(Error("failed to generate session"));` inside your catch handler